# What is the difference between ->assertSee and ->See

Tags: php, laravel-dusk, browser-testing

Simple question, can't find anything satisfying on Google.

What is the difference between `->assertSee` and `->See`?

Which should I use to check content from a page?

Comment: Where does the `->See()` method come from?

Comment: Someone used it in our project.  so assertSee is the mainstream one?

Comment: I've never seen this method. It's not available in Dusk, might be unique to your project.

Comment: ok thanks, changed them all and the test seems to still work so i am not going back ;-)